# How to validate multiple rule inputs in DMN camunda

Tags: decision-model-notation

Assume that I have two inputs (input1, input2), I can define DMN rule condition as follows:

input1 > 10 or input2 <= 10.

However, I would like to define a condition with multiple inputs:

input1 + input2 > 10

How can I do this using DMN?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found as follows:

```
<inputEntry id="id" expressionLanguage="juel"> <text>(input1 + input2) > 1.0</text>
</inputEntry>
```